# I can't connect to the postgresql database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

The project is working, in Java and spinning on the server.
I'm trying to connect to the postgresql database and I get this error:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Here are the settings from the file application.xml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @spring.profiles.active@
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    platform: convert
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mark_convert
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mark_convert
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog.xml
```

Here is the Docker-compose file

```
  postgres-converter:
    container_name: postgres-converter
    image: postgres:13.2-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=converter
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_converter_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Here are the connection settings
[image]

If someone changed the password in the database, then the Java application would not be able to work with this database?

I'll give you another file for liquibase, but it confused me even more, there are completely different names indicated.

```html
    <createTable  tableName="converter_history" schemaName="history">
        <column  name="id"  type="BIGINT"  autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints  primaryKey="true"  nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column  name="type"  type="varchar(20)"/>
        <column  name="pic_number"  type="varchar(4)"/>
        <column  name="part_number_oem"  type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="date_added" type="timestamp" defaultValueComputed="current_timestamp">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="result" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
```

Comment: looks like your db name is `converter` but in the connection string in `application.xml` the db name is `mark_convert`!

Comment: It also misleads me. But the developer of this project has disappeared and there is no one to ask. I tried to specify the DB name mark_convert in the connection. The same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not allowed to connect with a password.
Confirm whether the `pg_hba.conf` file has the following content.

/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```